# HTTP POST request test is not getting passed

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs, http-post

I wrote some nodejs codes to be evaluated by a particular test file, *candidate.test.js* but surprisingly the test keeps failing. Below is the error I am getting:

---

- Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
- Expected: 201
- Received: 500

---

I have below the snippet from both app.js and candidate.test.js.

**candidate.test.js**

```
const request = require('supertest');

const app = require('../app');

// ...
async function makeRegularGetRequest(requestBody) {
  return await request(app)
    .post('/restaurant')
    .send(requestBody)
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/);
}

  it('should create a restaurant given valid parameters', async () => {
    const requestBody = {
      name: '123',
      position: 200,
      category: 'Pizza',
      rating: 5,
    };
const createResponse = await makeRegularPostRequest(requestBody);
try {
      expect(createResponse.status).toEqual(201);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  });
// ...
```

**app.js**

```
// ...
app.post('/restaurant', (request, response) => {
  const id = generateRandomString();
  const { name, position, category, rating } = request.body;
  const restaurant = {
    name: name,
    position: position,
    category: category,
    rating: Number(rating),
    id: id,
  };
  restaurants.push(restaurant);
  response.send(restaurant).status(201);
});
// ...
```

I also tried sending only the statusCode to the page using `reponse.send(restaurant).status(201).statusCode`, but the error still comes out.

I tested this on Postman and it works really fine but it's strange that the test does not pass.

Comment: You can copy request code from postman also right side from this icon <> it's good for you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you console log before and after pushing to restaurants array

Comment: Do you mean I should log the restaurant object?

Comment: No, I mean to log before and after the restaurants array to know weather the error comes from it or not, you got error 500 which means internal server error so we don't know really where is the error in your server

Comment: I did that already and everything looked cleans when I run the file but when I run the test, console log does not work. When I remove ```restaurants.push(restaurant);```and run the test, it shows server timeout. If I remove the route, it show 404.

Comment: try something return await request(app)
    .post('/restaurant')
    .send(requestBody)
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/);
} instead of  .expect('Content-Type', /json/) just add .expect(201)

Comment: I was given the test file and the instruction given does not allow me to edit it.

Comment: are you sure that the app been required in the test file is required correctly? I mean is it the same app running of your server

Comment: Yes, because when I remove the route, it changes the error to 404, which means the route is not found.